# How to sweep from armory wallet?

Tags: wallet, armory, sweep

I recently tried to get started in Bitcoins, bought some online and received on an armory wallet. Little did i know i needed to download the full blockchain, that i have no space for.

I tried to sweep using armory private keys (wallet/backup this wallet/export key list) into electrum and several other wallet but the wallets can't seem to recognise the keys since the "sweep" button always stay grey.

I also tried to send the bitcoins to another address using omniwallet but armory can't recognise and sign the transaction file.

What can i do ? I feel like i'm out of options

Comment: Do you know what format the keys dumped from armory are? DO NOT post the actual keys, just describe the format of them. eg *"a long string of numbers/letters that starts with the number 5"* (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format)

Comment: Hey, thank's for the answer. Turns out dumbass me was always running armory in testnet (since it was the only one that appeared when i search i the search bar). I realised that after seeing that all my keys started with 9. After running armory in normal mode i was able to sweep my keys to electrum.